# How to move box up when doing mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to move boxes up when simply doing a mouseover. I can mouseover on each box, but can't get it to move up.
Here's my code:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.row {
 padding: 50px 0;
}
.post-item {
 outline: 1px solid red;
 padding: 50px 20px;
 border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.post-item:hover {
 outline: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
 }
```

Here's my [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/KgXLmr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `transform` like the following:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.post-item {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.post-item:hover {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your given examples did it by two CSS properties:

```
.post-item:hover {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transform: translate3d(0,-3px,0); /* This line defining how many pixel should move */
  transition: all .15s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1); /* This line defining transition time such as here: .15s */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code when you hover the element to move up.

```
  .post-item:hover{transform:translateY(-3%);}
```